# How to filter table data in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

```js
export class EmployeeDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  employees: any = [];
  public errorMsg;
  // you can define also below
  // errorMsg:any = [];
  constructor(private _employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this._employeeService.getEpmloyees().subscribe(
      data => (this.employees = data),
      error => (this.errorMsg = error)
    );
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.employees.filter = filterValue.trim().toLocaleLowerCase();
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p><input type="text" (keyup)="applyFilter($event.value)"></p>
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>NAME</th>
      <th>AGE</th>
      <th>Mobile</th>
    </tr>

    <tbody *ngFor="let employee of employees; i as index">
      <tr>
        <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.age}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.mob}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Above is my code I just wanted to know what is going wrong
in the filter method what I exactly need to change to make this work.
and how do I fetch properly filtered data?

Comment: What does the response of your data look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
export class EmployeeDetailsComponent implements OnInit {
      employees: any = [];
      allEmployees:any=[];
      public errorMsg;
      constructor(private _employeeService: EmployeeService) {}

      ngOnInit() {
        this._employeeService.getEpmloyees().subscribe(
          data => (
              this.employees = data,
              this.allEmployees=data;//You don't want to override you search data with all employee list
          ),
          error => (this.errorMsg = error)
        );
      }

      applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
         let filterValueLower = filterValue.toLowerCase();
         if(filterValue === '' ) {
             this.employees=this.allEmployees;
         } 
         else {
           this.employees = this.allEmployees.filter((employee) => employee.name.includes(filterValueLower)
         }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess the filter string should be applied to some field in the array to filter the data e.g. name:

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    this.employees.filter(i => i.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValue.toLowerCase());
  }
```

you also don't want to apply filter on every key up, until you want to use debounce.

Answer (score 1):

According to what you need, you need to use the `filter()` function on `this.employees` array and based on your requirement on which property you want to filter, either all or specific property of `employee` object, you can set your filter condition. Then your code will look something like this:

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
  let filterValueLower = filterValue.toLowerCase();
  this.employees = this.employees.filter((employee) => employee.id.includes(filterValueLower) || employee.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValueLower) || employee.age.toLowerCase().includes(filterValueLower) || employee.mob.toLowerCase().includes(filterValueLower));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

**template.html**

```
<input type="text" (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)"></p>
```

**component.ts**

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    let filterValueLower = filterValue.toLowerCase();
    if(filterValue === '' ) {
        this.employees
    } else {
       this.employees = this.employees.filter((employee) => 
                        employee.id.includes(filterValueLower) || 
                        employee.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterValueLower) || 
                        employee.age.toLowerCase().includes(filterValueLower) || 
                        employee.mob.toLowerCase().includes(filterValueLower));
  }
 }
```